# How to change data that comes from a text file in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js and made a simple app, where I have a text file called 'input.txt' with some data and printing it out in localhost. I would like to add some function, for example remove all *, but I get an error with split function. Can you help where I am going wrong? Is there a way to change text file data somehow?

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        var data = data.split('*')
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

and here is the example of 'input.txt'

```
veronika*sandra*carol*bye*
```

Comment: To remove all `*` use `replace(/\*/g, '')` instead of `split('*')`. Please have a look my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use split and join

```
let dataFile=data.split('*').join(' ');


res.write(dataFile);
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. I get an error SyntaxError: Identifier 'data' has already been declared
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

Comment: Can I see the data variable

Comment: ok i changed your let data to let test and turned it upside down and i think it is working now, thanks for pointing me to the right direction using let instead of var let test = data.split('*').join(' ');
        res.write(test);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check error and then it is safe to convert into a string like

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
            res.end();
        } else {
            data = data && data.toString().replace(/\*/g, '');
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        }
    });
}).listen(8080);
```